# Dynamically generated query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using mysql to create a search function from a database, however from the way the rest of the program is designed the user must only return 1 result from the info they enter. That is fine for me to program errors and such but I am having trouble accepting multiple strings as inputs to select the data from the table?

How do I make people be able to enter a combination of multiple fields (firstname, phone) etc. and come up with the results that match them without having the empty fields skew the results? i.e(Phone number is blank so only returning people with blank phone numbers)?

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `First_Name` = '$_SESSION[queryfname]
```

At the moment above is what the query is and I am unsure of what function to use (AND, OR) any help would be appreciated. Thanks it advance.

Comment: `..WHERE First_Name = '$_SESSION[queryfname] OR phone = 123456789`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this.

Comment: I think you are looking to build a dynamic query like a Prepared Statement

Comment: This does not work it returns all results if first name matches for example and phone number does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is something you would handle in your programming language (seems to be PHP here), and only query for the fields you are provided.  You could do that like so :

```
$wheres = array('1=1');
if($_SESSION['queryfname']){
  $wheres[] = "`First_Name` = '{$_SESSION['queryfname']}'";
}
if($_SESSION['querypnumber']){
  $wheres[] = "`Phone_Number` = '{$_SESSION['querypnumber']}'";
}
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE " . implode($wheres,' AND ');
```

however if you are limited to doing it in your SQL, you could do something like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM `users`
WHERE
(
  `First_Name` = '{$_SESSION['queryfname']}'
  AND
  `First_Name != ''
)
OR --Could also be AND
(
   `Phone_Number` = '{$_SESSION['querypnumber']}'
   AND
   `Phone_Number` != ''
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Right aha using the not equal to function I shall try this now.

Comment: This did not work is the best thing to do is construct multiple if statements to sort what fields are entered and incase sql queries inside?

Comment: Well, it should most certainly work, however I have now added a PHP way of doing things for you as well.

Comment: Careful, the 1=1 trick will not work with OR, you could use 2=1 instead

Comment: I ended up making an if query for every combination of search and that is working fine, You where the closest so I have marked you as correct Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try the limit:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `First_Name` = '$_SESSION[queryfname] LIMIT 1;
```